# Delete nodes of a word if they are not being used by another word in the Trie structure

Tags: python, trie

When deleting a word from a trie, I'm trying to delete the nodes of that word if they are not being used for another word.

So I don't want to just mark a node when a word is deleted. Unused nodes should really be removed.

If the word can't be found in the trie, I want the delete method to return False and if the deletion works it should return True.

This is my Trie class:

```
class Trie(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}
        self.end = "#"

    def append_word(self, word: str):
        node = self.children
        for c in word:
            node = node.setdefault(c, {})
        node[self.end] = self.end
```

Here's the `delete` method I tried to implement based on research:

```
    def delete(self, word):
        node = self
        parent = self
        for char in word:
            if char in node.children:
                parent = node
                node = node.children[char]
            else:
                return False
        if not node.children:
            del parent.children[char]
            del node
            return True
        else:
            node.end = "#"
            return True
```

What am I missing here?

I am calling the function like this, from an instance of the trie from another class:

```
self.trie.delete(user_input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues with your attempt are related with these two points:

- Your `append_word` method shows that nodes do not have a `children` property. They are dictionaries. The only object that has a `children` property is the `Trie` instance, and you only have one such instance. The rest of the structure is a nested dictionary that starts with that `children` property
- With `parent` you only retain the *last* parent, not all ancestors. To do it right you would need to backtrack over potentially multiple ancestors until you bump into an ancestor that is still in use for another word. So actually you need a list of ancestors instead of just one `parent` reference.

Here is the corrected implementation:

```
def delete(self, word):
    node = self.children
    stack = []
    for char in word:
        if char not in node:  # Word is not in the Trie
            return False
        stack.append(node)  # Collect as ancestor
        node = node[char]
    if self.end not in node:  # End-of-word marker is missing, so word is not in Trie
        return False
    del node[self.end]   # Remove end-of-word marker
    for char in reversed(word):  # Backtrack in reversed order
        if len(node):  # Still in use for another word?
            break
        node = stack.pop()
        del node[char]
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Touching upon @trincot's answer, I don't think it's memory efficient to use a stack. We can simply use a variable `lowest_node` to denote the point from where we can safely trim below. Here's my implementation -

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}
        self.endOfWord = False

class Trie:
    # omit the init etc.
    def delete(self, word):
        node = self.root
        lowest_node = self.root
        lowest_char = ''
        for char in word:
            if char not in node.children:
                return False
            if len(node.children) > 1 or node.endOfWord == True:
                lowest_node = node
                lowest_char = char
            node = node.children[char]
        if node.children:
            node.endOfWord = False
        else:
            lowest_node.children.pop(lowest_char)
        return True
```